# Why is the TypeName() function in VBA returning the interface name instead of the object name for InternetExplorer?

Tags: vba

The [TypeName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5422sfdf(v=vs.90).aspx) function is supposed to return a string representing the object name.  After testing this with other objects it seems to work.  However, for the InternetExplorer object it is [returning the IWebBroser2 interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752127(v=vs.85).aspx) instead.  This will prove it but please ensure Microsoft Internet Controls is referenced before running

```
Sub anotheroverflowquestion()

  'Turn on References to Microsoft Internet Controls

   Dim IE As New InternetExplorer


   MsgBox TypeName(IE)


End Sub
```

Comment: Probably because `coclass InternetExplorer` has `[default] dispinterface IWebBrowser2`.

Comment: Thanks, where did you find that out?

Comment: Opened the ieframe.dll with a viewer that can view the embedded type library.

Comment: Which viewer?  Is it available to download?

Comment: I tried to use Ispy and got a message "This file does not contain a managed assembly."

Comment: There are many. I happened to use [PEBrowse](http://www.smidgeonsoft.prohosting.com/pebrowse-pro-file-viewer.html), but it has its issues.